# Is there a way to use createAsyncThunk to axios.put using reduxtoolkit?

Tags: javascript, axios, redux-toolkit

Could someone direct me into the right direction to find out how to make a axios.put request using reduxtoolkit?

This is my projectsSlice file. The voteProject is where I am having problems. Im just trying hardcoded data for now to get this to work. When I run it without the arrow function it doesnt accept the data and throws an error saying <payloadtoolargeerror: request entity too large at readstream> when I run it as an arrow function as shown here it accepts the projects data but doesnt send the axios.put to db. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from '../axios';
import data from './data'

export const getProjects = createAsyncThunk(
    "projects/getProjects",
    async () => {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/v1/works')
        return response.data.data
    }
)

export const voteProject = (project) => createAsyncThunk(
    "projects/voteProject",
    async () => {
        const response = await axios.put("/api/v1/works/61fe5ee76b924c82c53b7513", {upvote: [1,2]})
        console.log("response: _____________________", response)
    }
)

// change the state based on the called functio
export const projectsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'projects',
    initialState: {
        projects: null,
        status: null,
    },
    reducers: {
        setUpvote: (state, action) => {
            const index = state.projects.findIndex((obj) => obj._id === action.payload.id);
            // console.log("Payload: ", action.payload)
            // console.log("Index: ", action.payload)
            if (action.payload.isDownvote === false) {
                return state.projects[index].upvote += 1;
            } else if (action.payload.isDownvote === true) {
                state.projects[index].upvote += 1;
                state.projects[index].downvote -= 1;
            }

        },
        setDownvote: (state, action) => {
            const index = state.projects.findIndex((obj) => obj._id === action.payload.id);
            if (action.payload.isUpvote === false) {
                state.projects[index].downvote += 1;
            } else if (action.payload.isUpvote === true) {
                state.projects[index].downvote += 1;
                state.projects[index].upvote -= 1;
            }
        },
        setSubractVote: (state, action) => {
            const index = state.projects.findIndex((obj) => obj._id === action.payload.id);
            if (action.payload.voteType === "upvote") {
                state.projects[index].upvote -= 1;
            } else if (action.payload.voteType === "downvote") {
                state.projects[index].downvote -= 1;
            }
        },
    },
    extraReducers: builder => {
        builder
            .addCase(getProjects.pending, (state, action) => {
                state.status = 'loading';
            })
            .addCase(getProjects.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.status = 'success';
                state.projects = action.payload;
            })
            .addCase(getProjects.failed, (state, action) => {
                state.status = "failed";
            })
    }
})

//action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { setUpvote, setDownvote, setSubractVote } = projectsSlice.actions;

export default projectsSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your thunk function to

```js
export const voteProject = createAsyncThunk(
  'projects/voteProject',
  async (data) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.put("/api/v1/works/61fe5ee76b924c82c53b7513", data)
      return response.data
    } catch (err) {
      // custom error
    }
  }
)

export const projectsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'projects',
  initialState: {
    projects: null,
    status: null,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(voteProject.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      // payload is the data response from thunk above
      // update your state
    })
    // add more case
  }
})
```

In your component:

```
import { voteProject } from './your-slice'
import { useAppDispatch } from '../store'

const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
const onVoting = () => {
  dispatch(voteProject({ // your data }))
    .unwrap()
    .then((originalPromiseResult) => {
      // handle result here
    })
    .catch((rejectedValueOrSerializedError) => {
      // handle error here
    })
}
```

Since Redux Toolkit v1.6 has RTK Query integrated in so you can use [rtk-query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) to write date fetching.